# Kubernetes YAML file - convert Azure to AWS ("file share" volume segment)

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I have my Azure Kubernetes YAML file which works completely in AKS.
Now I need to prepare it for AWS.
Could you please assist me what has to be changed?
I am specifically oriented that most probably file share segment must be modified since **"azureFile"** segment is specific to Azure (and probably related **volumes** and **volumeMounts** must be changed according to that)

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: frontarena-ads-win-deployment
  labels:
    app: frontarena-ads-win-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      name: frontarena-ads-win-test
      labels:
        app: frontarena-ads-win-test
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        "beta.kubernetes.io/os": windows
      restartPolicy: Always
      containers:
      - name: frontarena-ads-win-test
        image: local.docker.dev/frontarena/ads:wintest2
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
          - containerPort: 9000
        volumeMounts:
          - name: ads-win-filesharevolume
            mountPath: /Host
      volumes:
      - name: ads-win-filesharevolume
        azureFile:
          secretName: fa-secret
          shareName: fawinshare
          readOnly: false
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: fa-repo-secret
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: frontarena-ads-win-test
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: frontarena-ads-win-test
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 9001
    targetPort: 9000
  selector:
    app: frontarena-ads-win-test
```

Answer (score 0):

`azurefile` is one of the [Storage Classes provisionners](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/#provisioner), that you could replace with, for instance, a `AWSElasticBlockStore` ([AWS EBS](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/#aws-ebs))

But you might also benefit from [AWS SMS (AWS Server Migration Service)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/server-migration-service/latest/userguide/server-migration.html) in order to analyze your Azure configuration and generate one for AWS, as explained in "[Migrating Azure VM to AWS using AWS SMS Connector for Azure](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/migrating-azure-vm-to-aws-using-aws-sms-connector-for-azure/)" by [Emma White](https://www.linkedin.com/in/emmamckeewhite).
You will need to [Install the Server Migration Connector on Azure](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/server-migration-service/latest/userguide/Azure.html).
The tool has [limitations though](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/server-migration-service/latest/userguide/prereqs.html#limitations).

See also [AWS Application Migration Service](https://aws.amazon.com/application-migration-service/) for the applications part.